# How to show filters on table when using WP_List_Table

Tags: plugin-development, wp-list-table

I'm trying to show filters at the top of the table using the `WP_List_Table` class. But nothing shows up. Ive also checked the documentation but there's no example on how to use the method. Please see my code below.

**Class**

```
class Coup extends WP_List_Table
{
    public function display_tablenav( $position ) {
        if ( 'top' !== $position ) {
            parent::display_tablenav( $position );
        }
    }
}
```

**Calling the method**

`<?php $jUrlCoupon->display_tablenav('top'); ?>`

**Current Result**

Nothing happens, even an error is not showing up so maybe there's something I have to do?

Comment: `display_tablenav()` is not the correct method for showing the filters, but I'm curious whether that's the only code in your class?  Can we see your full class structure (or the full code if not too much)?